# I need a Java library to help me solve multi-times equations

Tags: java, binary, equation, quadratic

I just started using Java to simulate solar panel's performance, however the single diode model requires lots of calculations:

basically, each function is a function of the other, all of them of the variable of Rs, a.
two equations are available from f, f1.
how can i get the value of Rs, a.
I can extract Rs, a from the equations and take it to the equation of f, f1.
however, the equation will be of great difficulty to solve, as it has exp(), multi-times of the variable and ln()..
 is there any library to use to calculate the value of variables by given constraint?

the equations are basically like this:

```
v = 3.5a

ff0= 5/v+ln(5/v+0.7)/(5/v+1)

ffs = ff0*(1-Rs*1.1)+(Rs*8)^2
....
...
..
f:  9=constant1-ffs*((exp(v-4/Rs))-1)-(15+8*Rs)*a
f1: 9=15*(ffs*.....)
```

thank you.

Comment: What is a multi-times equation? Do you mean "polynomial series"?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't concisely characterized the kind of equations that you want to solve, but the examples look rather hairy.  If they are solvable (symbolically) then a commercial package like Mathematica is probably a good bet.

But I think you'd probably be better off asking this kind of question on the

```
http://math.stackexchange.com/
```

where real mathematicians hang out.  If nothing else they can characterize your equations for you and tell you if they are likely to be solvable.